# Rotas no ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tenho as seguintes rotas:

```
resources :roles do
  resources :role_permissions do
    patch 'toggle_action/:id' => 'role_permissions#toggle_action'
  end
end
```

Crio um link da seguinte maneira:

```
role_role_permissions_path(@role, @role_permission, permission_action)
```

Deveria montar uma rota semelhante à rota abaixo:

```
# => /roles/1/role_permissions/1/toggle_action/1
```

Mas está gerando uma rota como:

```
# => /roles/1/role_permissions/1.1
```

O que poderia ser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta adicionar um **alias** para a rota:

```
resources :roles do
  resources :role_permissions do
      patch 'toggle_action/:id' => 'role_permissions#toggle_action', as: :toggle_action
  end
end
```

e para usá-la:

```
role_role_permission_toggle_action_path(@role, @role_permission, permission_action)
```

Veja a rota:

> role_role_permission_toggle_action PATCH  /roles/:role_id/role_permissions/:role_permission_id/toggle_action/:id(.:format) role_permissions#toggle_action